# Updating after initial compile, Java

Tags: java, build, compilation

So I'm new to java (more familiar with python) so sorry if this is a really silly question. I have a folder of java files. I created a new directory and compiled the java files into it.

```
~ mkdir classes
~ javac -d classes my_code/*.java
```

Now, after initially compiling the code, I was able to run the scripts in terminal using:

```
java classes/some_script
```

Next, to make updates in the code I'm using a IDE (intellij). But after I save the some_script.java file the updates dont show up when I rerun the statement above in terminal.

Is there something I have to do (in terminal) to update the files so that when I rerun the statement in terminal the changes I made in the IDE show up? (ps I'm using a mac).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each time you modify the source code you need to compile the code. Contrary to python you cannot just save the file and run it.

Comment: @Richard Note that pretty much every IDE (Eclipse, IntelliJ) *will* automatically run the compile for you when you save. One more reason to use the tools consistently.